# MySQL column type returns decimal or bigint when i run "SELECT 0 AS COL .."

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When i run a select statment like

```
SELECT 0 AS COL FROM MYTABLE ..
```

Two different mysql installation returns different datatypes. One returns BIGINT second one is DECIMAL. for both cases jdbc driver is same and com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 5.1

Server Versions : 
5.1.69-community (returns BIGINT)
5.6.31 (returns DECIMAL)

Is there any configuration difference? I must get BIGINT both for two installations. is it directly related with mysql version?

Comment: Are you using JDBC? If so I would expect it to depend in the JDBC version you’re using (it’s probably provided by MySQL).

Comment: @Ole V.V. yes its jdbc com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 5.1

Comment: Version 5.1.69 came out on 18-Apr-2013. Time to upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You can force the issue with

```
 select CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS COL
```

Unsigned integers appear on the wire as BIGINTs.

Comment: Yes they are different versions:

One is 

5.1.69-community (returns bigint)
5.6.31  (returns decimal)

Comment: its ok but there are too many points in my application that uses SELECT 0 AS. It is not possible to change all in a reasonable period.